# Winforms DataBindings.Add for "Current - 1" and "Current + 1" in addition to "Current"?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

Subject says it all. My GUI is based on a DataTable and laid out like:

```
(current - 1, gray)    label 1/4000    label ABC

                       [ Navigate Previous button ]
(current, black)       label 2/4000    label DEF
                       [ Navigate Next button     ]

(current + 1, gray)    label 3/4000    label GHI
```

DEF is taken care of with `currName.DataBindings.Add ("Text", mybindingsource, "cname");`, but are ABC and GHI bindable with this approach?

Currently my workaround is to manually set the ABC and GHI labels procedurally on every call of `mybindingsource_CurrentChanged` event, but this seems sub-par because it's so manual and I lose the automatic formatting and DBNull handling that `DataBindings.Add` gives you for free.

What should I be doing instead?

(Yeah, I'm aware of DataRepeater, and I do use it on other forms, but it wasn't really suitable for this form for reasons that are too long to go into here and aren't relevant to the question.)

Comment: DataBindings can have events: Format and Parse.

Comment: I believe your current solution is fine, but if you are curious to know how to have a workaround using data-binding, as an option, you can use different `BindingSource` components to bind controls, then set their `Position` based on position of the main binding source in `PositionChanged` event of the main binding source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your current solution is fine, but if you are curious to know how to have a workaround using data-binding, as an option, you can use different `BindingSource` components to bind controls, then set their `Position` based on position of the main binding source in `PositionChanged` event of the main binding source.

**Example**

In below example, the main binding source is `currentBS` which `currentTextBox` is bound to it. `previousTextBox` shows previous item and `nextTextBox` shows next item:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var t = new DataTable();
    var tc = t.Clone();
    t.Columns.Add("C1");
    t.Rows.Add("A");
    t.Rows.Add("B");
    t.Rows.Add("C");
    t.Rows.Add("D");
    t.Rows.Add("E");
    currentBS.PositionChanged += (x, y) =>
    {
        if (currentBS.Position == 0)
            previousBS.DataSource = tc;
        else
        {
            previousBS.DataSource = t;
            previousBS.Position = this.currentBS.Position - 1;
        }
        if (currentBS.Position == currentBS.Count - 1)
            nextBS.DataSource = tc;
        else
        {
            nextBS.DataSource = t;
            nextBS.Position = this.currentBS.Position + 1;
        }
    };
    previousBS.DataSource = tc;
    nextBS.DataSource = tc;
    currentBS.DataSource = t;
    this.previousTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", previousBS, "C1");
    this.currentTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", currentBS, "C1");
    this.nextTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", nextBS, "C1");
}
```

Comment: Much cleaner than the procedural approach.